# What does `0+ptr` (0 plus a pointer) mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I found the following macro in the source code of Perl:

```c
#define GvGP(gv) (0+(gv)->sv_u.svu_gp)
```

Where `sv_u.svu_gp` is declared as `GP* svu_gp` in a union `sv_u`.

I can't find any definition of `GP`. However I am more confused about what 0 plus a pointer means. Could anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: `arco in the source code of Perl` Where exactly? Please post a link to it.

Comment: maybe to check if `svn_gp` is not `void*`. Or to check if it's an arthemtic type, eventually to make it it an l-value thus non-assignable

Comment: FYI, `GP` is defined in `perl.h` as `typedef struct gp GP`, and `struct gp` is defined in `gv.h`.

Comment: I wonder what the `0` brings? Wouldn't a unary `+` be enough?

Comment: I believe that is a debug leftover. probably initially there was non zero

Comment: Added the perl tag in case someone deeply familiar with the internals of perl sees it there and can explain the rationale.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, unary `+` does not work with pointers

Comment: @tstanisl Ahhh ... Thanks! Yet another difference between C and C++ I need to remember :-)

Comment: GP is a typedef in perl.h, for the gp structure defined in gv.h

Comment: Time for a `#define GvGP(gv) (GvEnsureRValue((gv)->sv_u.svu_gp))` for clarity?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I guess it is used to make it an R-value, what
makes it read-only in practice.

Example:
One can write

```
x = 1;
```

but this will not work:

```
0+x = 1;
```

---

**Edit**

Thanks to Dave Mitchell for pointing a related [commit](https://github.com/perl11/cperl/commit/c43ae56ff9cdb8e0fb3d1724f564378b031a4d49) in PERL repository.

> add GvCV_set() and GvGP_set() macros.
>
> and make GvCV() and GvGP() rvalue-only.
> ...

```
@@ -52,7 +57,8 @@ struct gp {
 #  define GvNAME_get(gv)   ({ assert(GvNAME_HEK(gv)); (char *)HEK_KEY(GvNAME_HEK(gv)); })
 #  define GvNAMELEN_get(gv)    ({ assert(GvNAME_HEK(gv)); HEK_LEN(GvNAME_HEK(gv)); })
 #else
-#  define GvGP(gv) ((gv)->sv_u.svu_gp)
+#  define GvGP(gv) (0+(gv)->sv_u.svu_gp)
+#  define GvGP_set(gv,gp)  ((gv)->sv_u.svu_gp = (gp))
 #  define GvFLAGS(gv)  (GvXPVGV(gv)->xpv_cur)
 #  define GvSTASH(gv)  (GvXPVGV(gv)->xnv_u.xgv_stash)
 #  define GvNAME_HEK(gv)   (GvXPVGV(gv)->xiv_u.xivu_namehek)
```

Indeed, the purpose was making `GvGP` read-only by making an r-value.

Comment: That makes very sense.  But it is still assignable if you do like *(0+x) = 1

Comment: @skankhunt76, yes, but this assigns data *pointed* by `0+x` while `0+x` itself is *not* assignable.

Comment: The commit which added the '0+' to the macro explicitly stated that it was to force the macro to be rvalue-only (at the same time adding the GvGP+set() macro).

Comment: @DaveMitchell, so my intuition was right :). Thanks for the finding. Could you share a link to the commit?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/c43ae56ff9cdb8e0fb3d1724f564378b031a4d49). Turns out it was one of my commits!

Comment: That might be considered an unfair advantage ;-)

Comment: Astonishing. Thanks for your help, it really amazed me that you have done that much of research for my tiny confusion.

Answer (score 11):

It makes it an rvalue i.e. you cannot do `&(0+(gv)->sv_u.svu_gp)`; furthermore, if it were instead an array, i.e. `0+"string"`, it would also decay the array to a `char *` from a `char [7]` -- so essentially `std::decay`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much.